# a function to create a sequence of integers with each integer repeated a given number of times [in R]

Tags: r, function, sequence

Is there a function to generate a sequence of integers in **R** where each integer is repeated a predefined number of times?

Example:

```
# 1 repeated twice, 2 repeated 5 times, 3 repeated 4 times and so on    
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3
```

I know the following function but it does not serve the purpose:

```
rep(1:5, each=3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe `rep()` can do exactly what you need:

```
rep(1:3, times = c(2, 5, 4))
# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Comment: my mistake was I passing the `times` vector argument to the `each` parameter.